# angular bootstrap 4 accordion load dynamically first tab show page load

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I need to show my accordion first tab open, when page load. currently all things working well. please check my code.

```
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" [id]="'heading'+data.id">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" [href]="'#collapse'+data.id" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+data.id">
            {{data.header}}
        </a>
    </h4>
</div>
<div [id]="'collapse'+data.id" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+data.id">
    <div class="panel-body">
        {{data.content}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check this demo [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-osvv72). How I open/show first accordion, when page load. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To default open the first accordion, you can do the below steps:

### First Solution

**Step 1**: Retrieve list index and pass to child component `HelloComponent` via property binding (Input).

> app.component.html

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <app-example *ngFor="let data of accordianData; index as i;" 
    [data]="data" 
    [index]="i" 
    class="panel panel-default">
  </app-example>
</div>
```

---

**Step 2**: Add `Input()` for index and implement logic in `OnInit` for `isAccordionOpen` (first index only to open by default).

> hello.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: `./hello.component.html`,
  styleUrls: [`./hello.component.css`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('data') data: any;
  @Input('index') index: number;

  isAccordionOpen: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isAccordionOpen = this.index === 0;
  }
}
```

---

**Step 3**: Add `*ngClass` to add "show" class based on `isAccordionOpen`.

> hello.component.html

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" [id]="'heading'+data.id">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" [href]="'#collapse'+data.id" aria-expanded="true"
      [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+data.id" (click)="isAccordionOpen = !isAccordionOpen">
      {{data.header}}
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div [id]="'collapse'+data.id" class="panel-collapse collapse" 
  [ngClass]="{'show': isAccordionOpen}" role="tabpanel"
  [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+data.id">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{data.content}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[First Solution: Complete source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ighvo1)

**Note**: *While I re-test the first element to collapse, I found out that the first element will be re-opened at first time. Suspect that there is a conflict with `data-toggle="collapse"` and `ng-show`.*

---

### Second Solution: Apply [Angular Bootstrap Collapse](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples)

*This solution is proposed to solve the first solution's bug as listed above.*

**Step 1**: Install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

```
npm install @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

---

**Step 2**: Add `NgbModule` import in app.module.ts

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [..., NgbModule]
  ...
})
```

---

**Step 3**: Retrieve list index and pass to child component `HelloComponent` via property binding (Input).

> app.component.html

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <app-example *ngFor="let data of accordianData; index as i;" 
    [data]="data" 
    [index]="i" 
    class="panel panel-default">
  </app-example>
</div>
```

---

**Step 4**: Add `Input()` for index and implement logic in `OnInit` for `isCollapsed` (first index only to open by default).

> hello.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  templateUrl: `./hello.component.html`,
  styleUrls: [`./hello.component.css`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('data') data: any;
  @Input('index') index: number;

  isCollapsed: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isCollapsed = this.index !== 0;
  }
}
```

**Step 5**: Apply Angular Bootstrap Collapse Component

> hello.component.html

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" [id]="'heading'+data.id">
  <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" (click)="collapse.toggle()" 
      [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+data.id"
      [attr.aria-expanded]="!isCollapsed">
      {{data.header}}
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
<div #collapse="ngbCollapse" [(ngbCollapse)]="isCollapsed" role="tabpanel" 
  [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+data.id">
  <div class="panel-body">
    {{data.content}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Second Solution: Complete source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dv4rhu)

Reference(s):

1. [Accordion example to open by default](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)